# Create complex Oracle report

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oraclereports

I have a `sale` table with the following columns:

```
name, city, area, target, date, sale
```

I want to show 8 different `area` data on a page. Please guide me what I need  write 8 queries or we have any other solution. To create a report in Oracle like I show in image please help me how I do this. Thanks waiting your kind response..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to organize your result set into groups. Groups indicate result set records that have something in common (such as all areas of New York).

In general, this structure will suit for your needs:

```
Group 1: City, Name -> Group 2: Area, Target -> Group 3: Date, Sale
```

For all groups declared, a repeating frame is created. You'll need to use a grid layout for the repeating frame of Group 2, in order to get the desired output.